# Como fazer um quadrado simples no Android?

Tags: android

Será que dá para fazer um quadrado cheio de uma cor sem todas as complicações? Digo complicações, pois os exemplos que vejo aqui na internet requer que crie outra classe, herdando de o View, fazendo do `drawRect()` na função `onDraw()` por meio do Canvas...

Em fim, será que tem uma coisa tão simples assim:

```java
int width = 10;
GridLayout gl = (GridLayout)findViewById( R.ids.mainGridLayout );
Square s = new Square( width );
gl.addView( s );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como me parece que você quer acrescentar um quadrado a um `GridLayout`, a solução mais simples seria criar uma View, definir uma cor de fundo e inclui-la no `GridLayout`:

```java
View view = new View(this);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
gl.addView(view);
```

Porém para sua informação o Android permite criar "shapes" (formas) como por exemplo retângulos (e portanto quadrados) e inclui-las como background de um layout como se fosse um *drawable*. Com isso seus quadrados podem ter:

- Bordas de cor e grossura customizada
- Beiradas arredondadas
- Degradês de fundo (na direção que você quiser)

Por exemplo:

#### res/drawable/meu_retangulo.xml:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <stroke
         android:width="2dp"
         android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#DD000000"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA" 
        android:angle="225"/> 
     <corners 
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Você inclui no layout assim:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/meu_retangulo" />
```

Comment: Será que não tem um meio de adicioná-la apenas com código? Por exemplo, `gv.addView( drawRect( 100, 100, 5, 5 ) )`? Ou será que não estou entendendo o conceito de Android e suas idiossincrasias?

Comment: O `drawRect()` é um recurso a ser usado em um objeto `Canvas`, que é uma "tela de pintura" que depois de desenhada precisa ser convertida para um bitmap a fim de ser exibida. A solução mais simples com código é criar uma View, atribuir a ela uma cor de fundo e adicioná-la ao GridLayout: `View v = new View(this); v.setBackgroundColor(cor); gl.addView(v);` seria isso?

Comment: Vou tentar com esse - mas acho que foi mais ou menos uma coisa assim que estava querendo! Obrigado

Comment: Ok, atualizei a resposta com o código-fonte e se tiver alguma outra requisição é só falar.

Answer (score 1):

Se tudo que você quer é um quadrado, por que não simplesmente usa um LinearLayout com uma cor de fundo?

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

É possível posicioná-o onde quiser inclusive por cima de outras views.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também criar sua imagem e usar como um recurso Drawable.

Comment: Pra quem não souber, pode dar uma referência de "recurso Drawable"? Valeu!